# Problem with TensorFlow 2.0 / Anaconda: unable to create process using 'path'

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda, conda

I have been using TF2.0 in Anaconda without any problems until yesterday. My pc had to be rebooted for Windows 10 x64 updates and Avast updates. From that point on, the Jupyter Notebook of the environment I created for TF did not open. After a few attempts I decided to reinstall Anaconda. I can use the base environment without issues but when I create an additional one and install TensorFlow, pip stops working. I can open Jupyter Notebook but TF won't work. This is what happens when I execute pip in the Anaconda Prompt:

```
(base) C:\Users\ABCD>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\ABCD\anaconda3
pyt3-TF2.0               C:\Users\ABCD\anaconda3\envs\pyt3-TF2.0
test1                    C:\Users\ABCD\anaconda3\envs\test1

(base) C:\Users\ABCD>conda activate test1
(test1) C:\Users\ABCD>pip
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\ABCD\anaconda3\envs\test1\python.exe C:\Users\ABCD\anaconda3\envs\test1\Scripts\pip-script.py '
(test1) C:\Users\ABCD>
```

When I execute pip in the base environment everything works fine. All the software is installed and updated to the latest stable versions. This is the code that I use to create and install TensorFlow:

```
conda create --name test1 python=3
conda activate test1
conda install tensorflow
```

I tried different approaches such as downgrading, creating environments with different names, installing packages in a different order and installing older versions. I observed that the problem occurs when I install TF. The problem happened after the computer restarted due to updates while I was using TF. I googled a little and found that this might be a problem with the path. When I wanted to use the same name as the older environments I got 'errno 13 permission denied'.

I really would like to keep on working with TF so any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! Have you googled problem with pip and error as you got on Windows?

Comment: Yes, I did, but I was not able to find a solution so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue and I want to share how I did it. The problem was Avast AV. The AV was not letting me install python or a package in the environment that I created. I temporarily deactivated the AV and I was finally able to install TF and Jupyter Notebook with no problems.